# ConcurrentHashMap not giving correct output in multi threaded application

Tags: java, concurrency

I created one example to understand concurrent HashMap but it seems to be giving indeterministic outout after 7-8 runs.

In my example, I create three threads(they are mimicking three services to fetch scores for Math,Science,English ) which update a concurent HashMap which has just 3 key value pairs (Keys are three names A,B,C and values at the end of the run should be cumulative score for three subjects)

I am posting the code below, pls advise.

Wrong Output is shown below (Correct one should end like be  All Done main : {C=27, A=57, B=42})

```
Within run Math : {C=0, A=0, B=0}
Within run Science : {C=0, A=0, B=0}
Completed Science : {C=10, A=39, B=29}
Completed Math : {C=10, A=39, B=29}
Within run English : {C=0, A=0, B=0}
Completed English : {C=18, A=57, B=42}
All Done main : {C=18, A=57, B=42}
```

ConcurrentHashMapExample class:

```
    package com.ll.thread.concurrency;

    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

    public class ConcurrentHashMapExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>   concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
            concurrentHashMap.put("A", 0);
            concurrentHashMap.put("B", 0);
            concurrentHashMap.put("C", 0);
            CountDownLatch  countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);

            Runnable runnableScience = new Worker(concurrentHashMap , "Science" , countDownLatch);
            Runnable runnableMath = new Worker(concurrentHashMap , "Math" , countDownLatch);
            Runnable runnableEnglish = new Worker(concurrentHashMap , "English" , countDownLatch);

            new Thread(runnableScience , "Science").start();
            new Thread(runnableMath ,"Math").start();
            new Thread(runnableEnglish ,"English").start();

            try {
                countDownLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("All Done " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : "+concurrentHashMap);




            concurrentHashMap = null;



        }

    }
```

Worker class:

```
    package com.ll.thread.concurrency;

    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

    public class Worker  implements Runnable{

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>  concurrentHashMap ;
        String threadName = "";
        CountDownLatch  countDownLatch ;

        public Worker(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> concurrentHashMap,
                String subject, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
            this.concurrentHashMap = concurrentHashMap;
            this.threadName = subject ;
            this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Within run " +Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : "+concurrentHashMap);
            try{
         for(Iterator<String>  iterator = concurrentHashMap.keySet().iterator() ;   iterator.hasNext();){
            String key = iterator.next();

            //synchronized (this) {


            if("Math".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
            if("A".equals(key))
                concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +20);
            else if("B".equals(key))
                concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) + 15);
            else if("C".equals(key))
                concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +10);
            }else

            if("Science".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                if("A".equals(key))
                    concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +19);
                else if("B".equals(key))
                    concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +14);
                else if("C".equals(key))
                    concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +9);
                }
            else
                if("English".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                    if("A".equals(key))
                        concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +18);
                    else if("B".equals(key))
                        concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +13);
                    else if("C".equals(key))
                        concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +8);
                    }

            }
        // }
            }
            finally{

                System.out.println("Completed " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + concurrentHashMap);
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
         }
        }
```

Comment: What did you expect? The `Concurrent` (in `ConcurrentHashMap`) means, that the map takes care of synchronisation as far as it needs to in order to protect its internal structures. It doesn't mean, that using it would automagically fix race conditions in the code using the map.

Comment: `concurrentHashMap.put(key, concurrentHashMap.get(key) +19);` is not atomic: the map may be updated between the get and the put...

Comment: you are not using it correctly from the shown code! I would recommend that you start with reading the javadocs for the interface ConcurrentMap (ConcurrentHashMap is an implementation) and in particular understand why the new methods were needed

Comment: thanks..reviewed the docs..seems my use case was not appropriate to test ConcurrentHashmap.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need `ConcurrentHashMap` in your test. You initialize map before your threads are executed. Instead you can use regular `HashMap` parametrized by `String` key and `AtomicInteger` value:

```
HashMap<String, AtomicInteger> concurrentHashMap = ...
concurrentHashMap.put("A", new AtomicInteger(0));
...
```

Then you can atomically increase value of `AtomicInteger` instance in each thread:

```
concurrentHashMap.get(key).addAndGet(20);
```